# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dev0'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, oauth

I got this error while running my app in command line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 199, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.ops = PostGISOperations(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 158, in __init__
    if self.spatial_version < (1, 3, 4):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 252, in spatial_version
    vtup = self.postgis_version_tuple()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 426, in postgis_version_tuple
    version = self.postgis_lib_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 406, in postgis_lib_version
    return self._get_postgis_func('postgis_lib_version')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 396, in _get_postgis_func
    with self.connection.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 515, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 157, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 129, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.set_autocommit(True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 333, in set_autocommit
    self._set_autocommit(autocommit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 172, in _set_autocommit
    if self.psycopg2_version >= (2, 4, 2):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 201, in psycopg2_version
    return tuple(int(v) for v in version.split('.'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 201, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(int(v) for v in version.split('.'))
```

I installed the necessary modules. I am using Django version 1.6. The same app runs smoothly in my windows laptop but when I migrated it in a Linux OS, the errors shows.

Comment: Is this full traceback? Didnt get final error statement.

Comment: I agree with the interpreter, `'dev0'` is not a valid integer.

Comment: The final error statement is the question.

Comment: How do you run the app from command line?

Comment: Locate the app first then type `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: It looks like you have a development version of postgresql_psycopg2. Have your tried using a virtual env instead of your distro's packages?

Comment: I tried both but same error.